# Why is my Python 3 file loop not being entered?

Tags: python

My code is:

```
f=open(filein)
print f
print f.read()

for row in f:
    print '0'
```

The first two print statements print a file object and lines from the file as expected but the `print '0'` never happens. It also doesn't happen if I comment out the first two prints. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f.read()` advances the file pointer to the end of the file. There's nothing left for the iterator to read, so the loop isn't entered.

You might want `f.readline()` to read just a *single* line, and have the loop iterate over the rest. However, mixing direct reads and iteration tends not to work properly, as it interferes with the internal buffering. In that case, use `next` instead:

```
with open(filein) as f:
    print(next(f))  # First line
    for row in f:   # Remaining lines
        ...
```

Comment: You are right! FYI: my question says it still does it when these lines are commented out. But there was another line reading the file (I did not think it was!) that I did not include.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted what you meant by "it also doesn't happen".

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open(filein)
print(f)

for row in f:
   print('0')

f = f.read()
```

This should fix the problem. Why you trying to read prior to iteration ?

Comment: Thanks, sorry chepner answered first. I was reading to see if there was something in the file.